# Display 2 content type in front page

Tags: views, theming

I am learning Drupal 8, i have 2 content type (Notices, Plan), i want my front page look like this:

**List entries of Notices**

- item 1
- item 2
- item n

Pager of list Notices

**List entries of Plan**

- item 1
- item 2
- item n

Pager of list Plan

Can i do this in some way?

Comment: I think you need to create two Views block for each content type. And add these blocks for the front page only on your content region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest possible way is to create a Views page and a Views block.
Then change the front page path with the one you used for the View (Configuration > Basic site settings > FRONT PAGE)
Then create the block instance in the Content region (Structure > Block layout)

Also, make sure you are using 2 different Pager ids in your view (in your view, under Pager > Settings > Pager ID) You may just use 1 for one of the views and 2 for the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You can display entries as block with pagination by using [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module. To know how to create block, watch [views block](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BebR07kucT4) tutorial.

I hope this would help.